# Issues using array in blade file - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, laravel-blade, stringify

I am having issues while using a foreach loop to iterate my array. When I do, it seems to strip the element names away and prevents me from referencing the array as I would expect to be able to.

Here is the JSON that we are taking from the database:

```
{"i": "", "ca": "", "gh": "5", "kh": "6", "mg": "", "ph": "4", "sg": "", "sr": "", "nh3": "1", "no2": "2", "no3": "3", "po4": "", "tds": "7", "date": "2018-04-05"}
```

I then decode it in my controller:

```
$params = json_decode($aquarium->parameters, true);
```

Pass it to the view:

```
return view('pages.aquarium.view', compact('aquarium', 'params', 'stocks', 'settings'));
```

And use it in a foreach loop:

```
@if(is_array($params))
    @foreach($params as $param)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $params['date'] }}</td>
            <td class="ammonia-col">{{ $param['nh3'] }}</td>
            <td class="nitrite-col">{{ $param['no2'] }}</td>
            ...
       </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

However, when I var_dump the original $params, I get this:

```
array(14) { ["i"]=> string(0) "" ["ca"]=> string(0) "" ["gh"]=> string(1) "5" ["kh"]=> string(1) "6" ["mg"]=> string(0) "" ["ph"]=> string(1) "4" ["sg"]=> string(0) "" ["sr"]=> string(0) "" ["nh3"]=> string(1) "1" ["no2"]=> string(1) "2" ["no3"]=> string(1) "3" ["po4"]=> string(0) "" ["tds"]=> string(1) "7" ["date"]=> string(10) "2018-04-05" }
```

Using var_dump on the $param gives this:

```
string(0) "" string(0) "" string(1) "5" string(1) "6" string(0) "" string(1) "4" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(0) "" string(1) "7" string(10) "2018-04-05"
```

This prevents me from being able to reference it as $param['x'], and returns an Illegal String Offset error. I'm not sure why this is, as it was working when I was manually crafting the JSON. Now that I am creating an object and then using JSON.stringify, it's breaking. I know that currently there is only one set, but eventually there will be many sets of data within the JSON so the foreach loop will be required to iterate through them.

For reference, my old way of handcrafting the JSON:

```
var params = '[{ "date":"'+date+'", "nh3":"'+ammonia+'", "no2":"'+nitrite+'", "no3":"'+nitrate+
        '", "ph":"'+ph+'", "gh":"'+gh+'", "kh":"'+kh+'", "tds":"'+tds+'", "sg":"'+sg+'", "po4":"'+
        phosphate+'", "ca":"'+calcium+'", "mg":"'+magnesium+'", "i":"'+iodine+'", "sr":"'+strontium+'" }]';
```

And, the new way:

```
var params = {
            date: date,
            nh3: ammonia,
            no2: nitrite,
            no3: nitrate,
            ph: ph,
            gh: gh,
            kh: kh,
            tds: tds,
            sg: sg,
            po4: phosphate,
            ca: calcium,
            mg: magnesium,
            i: iodine,
            sr: strontium
        };
```

In the AJAX request I then call JSON.stringify(params), and it's appropriately stored as valid JSON within the database.

Looking at this, I think I have figured out the issue. It's saving the JSON without the square braces. I'm not sure the proper terminology there, or how to append it in without manually crafting the JSON. While I can go back to that way, it seemed improper and it was a hassle to work with if I needed to change the data.

How would I appropriately cast the JSON into my database with the square bracing, to form a collection of JSON objects so that I may properly use a foreach loop to iterate over it?

Comment: A square bracing means it's an array in JSON terminology. What you can do to store it as an array is to be sure the collection is within a PHP array before you `json_encode` your php. I guess if you json encode an array you should get a json with square brackets surrounding all.

Comment: Also notice you did `$params['date']` within the foreach loop above. That should be `$param['date']`

Comment: @MarkSkayff `$param` in the loop is only the array value. It knows nothing about the `key`, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Alright, so in the controller I used json_decode on the passed in data to convert it to an array, and then did json_encode to convert to JSON and stored it. However, it still doesn't store it as an array in the database.

Comment: Yes sorry, $params['date'] is a holdover from bug testing this problem. The issue is found with $param['date']

Comment: Ok, what I see now, this line `{"i": "", "ca": "", "gh": "5", "kh": "6", "mg": "", "ph": "4", "sg": "", "sr": "", "nh3": "1", "no2": "2", "no3": "3", "po4": "", "tds": "7", "date": "2018-04-05"}` represents an object. You are trying to convert this to an array. And then you are looping through this array. Do you understand that you are looping through every individual value. Unless your object represents just a single value in a larger array.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
Based on the new information, part of the problem as you say is that you were storing the data as a one-dimensional array when in fact you should have been storing it as a two-dimensional array.

With that in mind, your JSON decoded array would look like this:

```
$params = [
    [
        'i'  => '',
        'ca' => '',
        'gh' => '5',
        'kh' => '6',
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Thus, when you iterate over your params array you'd want to do the following:

```
@if (is_array($params))
    @foreach ($params as $param)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $param['date'] }}</td>
            <td class="ammonia-col">{{ $param['nh3'] }}</td>
            <td class="nitrite-col">{{ $param['no2'] }}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Finally, to simplify the saving and retrieving `JSON` values from an Eloquent model, you may want to consider using casting.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

```
class Aquarium extends Model
{
    // ...

    protected $casts = [
        'parameters' => 'array',
    ];

    // ...
}

$aquarium = Aquarium::find(1);

$aquarium->parameters = [
    [
        // ...
    ]
];

$aquarium->save();
```

Comment: So I've got the Blade syntax like so, now:
`@foreach($params as $key => $param)
    <tr>
     <td>{{ $param }}</td>`

I don't necessarily want to output the key in each <td> element, as there is a heading for it. Is there a way to select which value I want? Like param['date'], but clearly that syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @LiamBull - see my edit. From the sounds of things, you don't actually need the `foreach` loop at all.

Comment: I do need the foreach loop. The problem is that when I hand wrote the JSON, it was stored as an array. That's because this JSON object will be stored as one of many, so I need to use the foreach to iterate through each array. The root of the problem is how it's being stored, it seems. It stores the JSON without the square brackets that  denote it as an array.

See the way it was handwrote at the bottom of the question, versus the JSON at the top without the square braces.

Comment: JSON is Javascript Object Notation. Arrays in JavaScript have no concept of string keys. They can only be numerically indexed. Thus when you convert your array to JSON, it makes it an object. This isn't a problem though, because when you decode it, you're casting it to an array with `json_decode($params, true)`.

Comment: Further, the `$params` array you have posted is not a nested array. It has a flat structure. So either I'm misunderstanding you, or the `$params` example you've posted isn't truly representative of the data structure.

Comment: I asked the wrong question, this is my bad. The issue was in how I was storing the JSON. I'll post an answer to my question and explain.

Comment: Finally, it's worth mentioning that Eloquent models have a `$cast` property, which can be used to `JSON` encode and decode your array value automatically, without you needing to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not in the retrieval of the JSON it was in how I was storing it. I stored it like so:

```
var params = {
        date: date,
        nh3: ammonia,
        no2: nitrite,
        no3: nitrate,
        ph: ph,
        gh: gh,
        kh: kh,
        tds: tds,
        sg: sg,
        po4: phosphate,
        ca: calcium,
        mg: magnesium,
        i: iodine,
        sr: strontium
    };
```

When I needed to store it like:

```
var params = [{
        date: date,
        nh3: ammonia,
        no2: nitrite,
        no3: nitrate,
        ph: ph,
        gh: gh,
        kh: kh,
        tds: tds,
        sg: sg,
        po4: phosphate,
        ca: calcium,
        mg: magnesium,
        i: iodine,
        sr: strontium
    }];
```

As there will be multiple JSON objects stored in the single database field, removing the foreach loop isn't possible.

Comment: If you're storing multiple JSON objects, will they all have the same keys and structure?